# returning date from 30 days ago if current date is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a field that is a `DATETIME` field that may be null.  If that field is null, I want to return the date from 30 days ago.  I have tried the following:

```
SELECT ISNULL(lastupdatedatetime, GETDATE() - 30) from .......

SELECT CASE WHEN lastupdatedatetime is null then GETDATE() - 30 ELSE lastupdatedatetime from ....
```

In both cases I keep getting `2000-01-01 00:00:00:000`

How can I get the result from `GETDATE()` that I'm looking for when `lastupdatedatetime` is null?

Comment: If you run this what do you get? `select DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())`

Comment: Your first expression, `ISNULL(lastupdatedatetime, GETDATE() - 30)` should do what you want.

Comment: Not able to reproduce: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b3e/1  Are you sure that `lastupdatedatetime` is null when you think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN lastupdatedatetime is null then DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()) ELSE lastupdatedatetime from ..
```

That should work.

Comment: Apologies, but still getting 2000-01-01.

Comment: While it's purely symantics, when using DATEADD, it's always easier to just write out the datepart.  Don't abbreviate d or s or w.  The abbreviations can get confusing, especially `wk` for week instead of `w` and `yy` instead of `y`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Try this: SELECT lastupdatedatetime, (CASE WHEN lastupdatedatetime is null then DATEADD(d,-30,GETDATE()) ELSE lastupdatedatetime END) from ..

Comment: What result did you get ?

Comment: Are you sure that the date from the computer running sql server is ok?

Comment: No, it's not.  I just found out a co-worker was attempting to "help" me behind my back and he populated the NULL dates with 2000-01-01.  I'll be back to mark an answer after I'm done beating this n00b.

Comment: Jajaja such a kind of help isn´t helping in any way!

Comment: How thoughtful of your coworker!  Glad you got it figured out.